# How to call a method in Activity from a CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter

I have an `image` in `feed_item.xml` that is inflated in the `custom adapter`.I am able to handle click events for the image.

I Have a `relative layout` in my `activity_main` that is rendered `player.setVisibility(View.GONE);` when my `Main Activity` is launched.I would like to `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` of this layout when my image in the row is clicked.

I have trouble relating the two layouts with my `Custom Adapter` and `Main Activity`.Any suggestions will be appreciated!!

**FeedListAdapter.java**

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);


        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());
        String fontPath = "fonts/Lato-Light.ttf";

        // Loading Font Face
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), fontPath);

        // Applying font
        name.setTypeface(tf);

        ImageView play=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Show Layout!",                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        ImageView options=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.options_popup);
        options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showFilterPopup(view);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

RelativeLayout player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView mToolBarTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_toolbar_title);
        mToolBarTextView.setText("Home");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        listView = (InnerGridView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        player = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.player);
        player.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use interface and on image click call that interface and implement your main activity to that inteface

Comment: can i implement more that one interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own interface with a method like this

```
 public interface OnClickInMyAdapterListener {
    public void onItemclicked();
  }
```

than your activity should implement this interface and override its method

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickInMyAdapterListener  {
   ...
   ...
}


@Override
public void onItemclicked() {
  // do what you want
}
```

change your adapter in order to recive the interface

```
     private OnClickInMyAdapterListener  myActivityInterface;

     public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems, OnClickInMyAdapterListener  myActivityInterface ) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.feedItems = feedItems;
            this.myActivityInterface= myActivityInterface;

        }
```

in the activity pass the interface to the adapter

```
listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems, (OnClickInMyAdapterListener ) this);
```

and use it in your adapter wherever you want

```
this.myActivityInterface.onItemclicked();
```

... This solution is useful also if your adapter is used in more diffrent activites

Comment: Another thing if you may,i would like to show a toast of the title of the row when the image is clicked..jus check out the adapter...How do i handle this?

Comment: you could define the method of the interface onItemclicked with a parameter in order to pass a string or whatever you want

Comment: I have asked this as a question,Please check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903974/how-to-show-title-of-a-row-in-a-textview-in-main-activity-when-an-image-in-the-r/31904116?noredirect=1#comment51723614_31904116)  .I would appreciate it.

Comment: For some reason in another project this doesnt seem to work when you use  this.myActivityInterface.onItemclicked(); But instead i used (myActivityInterface).onItemclicked();

Answer (score 1):

You can write one public method in Activity

And cast your activity context to your Activity

```
((MainActivity)activity).doSomething();
```

activity is context you are passing to adapter

doSomething is method in activity

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting OnClickListeners on the Views within your custom Adapter, you should call:

```
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

And have your Activity implement `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i am avoiding listview's click event

Comment: The problem with your approach is that your adapter will not remember the rows of the Views your are interacting with. ListView and its brethren constantly recycle their Views to keep memory usage down. If you're relying on the onClickListener to remember the row in which it was set--you shouldn't be, because it won't.

Comment: So for example if i would like to show a toast of the title of the row when the image is clicked..(jus check out the code of my adapter) it wouldnt be possible?

Comment: I'm saying I've experienced a LOT of issues trying to get OnClickListeners to work in rows within an adapter. If your list doesn't exceed the size of the screen, you may never notice. But if it DOES, you will. I encourage you to experiment, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I actually have.I try to display the title of the row when the image is clicked and it only retuurns the title of the first row in all cases.Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I mean i did the same project but i was handling  click events on the adapter and it worked.I cant replicate the same because in my previous case i was displaying an alert dialog with the row title.In this case i am trying to inflate a text view that exists in my activity xml.Is there a work around?

Comment: I honestly think the workaround is to rethink your design. Trying to figure out exactly which view within a row in an adapter gets clicked is a great way to waste hours and hours of your life. And you still won't succeed.