# How to show title of a row in a textview in Main Activity when an image in the row is clicked

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a `custom adapter` with an `image` in each `row`.On clicking the `image` i would like to display the `title` of the `row` that the image is part of.

I have implemented an `interface` in my `activity` that allows me to display a `relative layout` whenever the `image` is clicked where the `textview` that displays the row title exists.This `relative layout` is in in my **`activity_main.xml.`**

**Problem:** I have been able to accomplish all his except that **only the title of the first row is displayed across all the other image clicks in my listview.**

**Also:** I know that setting `listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` is the best way to go because this can handle the `position` of the `title` but i cannot use this as per my requirements.Is there a way to hack this?

So that my `textview` displays the title of the row that is different in each case?

**MainActivity.java:**

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FeedListAdapter.AdapterCallback {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    RelativeLayout error, player;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://10.0.3.2/main_feed_warship/main_feed.js";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView mToolBarTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_toolbar_title);
        mToolBarTextView.setText("Home");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        
        player = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.player);
        player.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ImageView cancel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                player.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }

                ;
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

    }

    
    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onMethodCallback() {
      
      //On Image click this relative layout is called
      
        player.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      
      //And the title of the row with the image that is clicked is displayed
      //Only the first row title is dispalyed across all image clicks
      
        String name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name))
                .getText().toString();
        TextView title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.music_title);
        title.setText(name);

    }
}
```

**FeedListAdapter.java:**

```js
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    String title;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        try {
            this.mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) activity);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());
        String fontPath = "fonts/Lato-Light.ttf";

        // Loading Font Face
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), fontPath);

        // Applying font
        name.setTypeface(tf);
        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);
        timestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

//The image in each row that is clicked to call the method below from my activity

        ImageView play=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback();

                } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
                }
            }
        });

        

        return convertView;
    }
    public static interface AdapterCallback {
        void onMethodCallback();
    }
   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but did you try utilizing the Tag. It goes like this:

1- In your adapter, set the ImageView tag to be the TextView (title) id:

```
feedImageView.setTag(name.getId());
```

2- When the imageView is clicked, you get the tag (i.e. the id of the TextView).

```
feedImageView.getTag();
```

3- Now, you have the correct reference to your title.

---

I'm not sure if passing the TextView id will be enough, but I think utilizing the Tag is the way to go. You just need to figure out what you should pass, and where you should pass it. **FYI**, you could pass the title (as a string) in the tag!

Comment: Interesting.Let me try this.

Comment: Also is it possible to like inflate a different layout when my image is clicked?I maean this way i could pass the title easily as a string.

Comment: I don't know if you could. Haven't done much inflating lately :)

Comment: `feedImageView.getTag();` is this set on my adapter or activity?

Comment: This should be used when you want to display the title. The Activity In your case (typically inside your ImageView clickListener).